# Using nullable for Foreign Key in Entity Framawork

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I use EF Code First approach in an ASP.NET MVC project and I have PK-FK relations on several entities as shown below:

```
public class Staff
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //Foreign key for Project
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}



public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Staff> Staffs { get; set; }
}
```

On the other hand, sometimes there is a need to use nullable FK values and in that case I create dummy record as N/A as FK is required property that seems to em ugly :( I know I can easily use nullable value for the related FK property, but I am not sure if it is a good approach or not. And what is the pros and cons using this approach (I know a pros of required FK : Data integrity :)

Secondly, should I use 0 or null value for the nullable FK? Why?

Comment: If you want to have the ProjectId optional/nullable just change the data type to int?  which is the same as Nullable<int> and should make that column in the database allow nulls. This is fine for a foreign key.

Comment: @Jon Thanks for reply Jon. What about my 2nd question? **should I use 0 or null value for the nullable FK? Why?**

Comment: Always null.  0 will not work, it will give you a SQL Foreign key violation error because there is no Project with an Id of 0.

Comment: Ok, I was already trying to get rid of 0 :) In that case I can use null. Is there any pros and cons using this approach? Because I will also update my some other entities in order to get rid of dummy records?

Comment: Using a null on a foreign key column is the recommended way. There is no cons to this.

Comment: @Jon Many thanks again for your kind helps... Voted up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a dummy record is not right, the correct approach here is to use an `int?` for the foreign key relation, [see here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx):

> If the data type of `GradeId` is nullable integer, then it will create a
>   null foreign key.
>
> ```
> public class Student 
> {
>     public int Id { get; set; }
>     public string Name { get; set; }
>
>     public int? GradeId { get; set; }
>     public Grade Grade { get; set; } 
> }
> ```
>
> The above code snippet will create a nullable `GradeId` column in the
>   database because we have used `Nullable<int>` type (`?` is a shortcut for
>   `Nullable<int>`)

An alternative approach would be removing `ProjectId` from the staff (Convention 3 in the above document):

```
public class Staff
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Staff> Staffs { get; set; }
}
```